# Django: How to make model attribute dependent on foreign key present in that model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, foreign-keys

I have two models in Django : State and City

```
class State(models.Model):
    #regex = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z]$', re.IGNORECASE)
    name_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]+$',
                                message="Name should only consist of characters")
    name = models.CharField(validators=[name_regex], max_length=100, unique=True)

class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]+$',
                                message="Name should only consist of characters")
    name = models.CharField(validators=[name_regex], max_length=100, unique=True)
    postalcode = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

In city model I have attribute state which is foreign key from State model. In city model I want to make attribute name dependent on state attribute, as one state will have one city with same name but one city name can be in many states.
Like City Udaipur is in both Rajasthan and UttarPradesh in India, but Rajasthan will have single city as Udaipur.

Comment: What do you mean by dependent? Are you talking about having validation?

Comment: Yes if we can put any validation while applying "POST" method?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a `unique_together` constraint on your `City` model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Something like this:

```py
class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]+$',
                                message="Name should only consist of characters")
    name = models.CharField(validators=[name_regex], max_length=100, unique=True)
    postalcode = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["state", "name"]
```

Comment: Hey this works by removing "unique=True" from name field. But now also I get one problem that field name with uppercase and lowercase are considered as different. I want Udaipur/udaipur/udaiPur all should be considered as same. So how to implement this?